# Too much response from a lot of request puts stress on the server

Tags: web-services, api, server

It's clear that a server with a lot of http requests from others puts stress on the server. But what about the responses from other servers.. Let's say my server or machine requested 10000 times from different servers and each will throw back a response data, will those response data put stress on my server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simple answer will be "depends on response data size and how you process those data".

In general, you should consider at least the following

- impact on network. 10k responses with 1mb size each is not the same as 10k responses with 100mb each.
- what kind of data you have in response and what type of calculation/modification you do with it?
- are you then storing responses in any storage (on server side / local storage, DB) and how much efforts it takes.

Comment: So, in other words it's a possibility that there can be a stress

Comment: @DeanChristianArmada yes, it can, but you need to measure. You may do stress-test/load test for your service and analyze results.

Comment: ok actually I'm just curious and I can't find any topic regarding this.. I have an idea that it can but I just want to make sure and want to hear other opinions.. Thanks!